# Generating random yet good-looking, different colors?

Tags: c#

Is there any well-known method for generating random, good looking and yet distinctive colors? I've worked with this before, and managed to generate colors at random. However, either they had a great chance of turning out "ugly" (yellow-ish brown, green-ish gray and others), or they turned out to be almost the same.

Now, as for measuring if two colors are almost the same, it's quite easy to just take the color channels and compare the differences between them.

I suspect that I will always need to generate between 1 and 15 colors.

**Edit** It's for some graphing stuff I am making in JavaScript. That may help you understand why I am in need of this.

Comment: Why not just hard-code 15 colors that look great together?

Comment: Because in rare scenarios, I will need way more. I'm in a situation where I don't want to limit the amount of elements for the user to being 15 always.

Comment: Are you sure colors alone is enough to represent this? The more colors you use, the harder it will be to distinguish them? Have you considered using symbols/icons as well?

Comment: It's a graph comparing students in a class. Therefore, icons can't be used I'm afraid.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I assume you're randomizing in the RGB color space; if you use a different color space, e.g. HSB, it is easier to determine whether two colors are similar, and you can limit the range of each axis to exclude 'ugly' colors.

For example, you may want to create the first color using:

- full range hue
- full saturation (100%)
- brightness in the upper 50%

And then a contrasting color using:

- first color's hue +/- a certain random value
- full saturation (100%)
- brightness in the lower 50%, but maxing at enough distance vs. the first color

The possibilities are endless, but the key idea is that HSB is a more 'natural' color space to randomize over, because you control the perceived properties of a color (hue, saturation, brightness), not the technical properties (intensities of three channels).

Answer (score 3):

I don't know about selecting single colors, since "ugly" and "good-looking" are very subjective terms.

Color schemes, or sets of colors that match, on the other hand, have some theory behind them, and it's very possible to select random colors that go together well.

Check out this website: [Color Scheme Designer](http://colorschemedesigner.com/).

Answer (score 1):

When implementing HSB for a graphing tool that did mostly line graphs, I found that the HSB model gave me great control on generating random colors, but it was still very difficult to find colors that didn't look the same when next to each other. I imagine it was worse for those folks with worse vision than mine (older people with trifocals, etc..).

Based on that experience, I recommend that you don't limit yourself to color. Use shapes and patterns along with a hard-coded set of colors that you randomly pick from.